# Грамотная реализация приложения клиент-сервер для передачи файла

Tags: java, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер

Хочу реализовать такую задачу.

Есть приложение по учёту компьютерного железа на предприятии (какой тип устройства, какая модель, на какой компьютер и когда были поставлены). Свойств всего 4 (тип устройства, модель устройства, имя компьютера, дата). По закрытию приложения эта таблица должна сохраниться на сервере предприятия в виде файла (по открытии приложения, соответственно загрузить в таблицу данные из этого файла на сервере).

Подскажите в какую сторону копать по вопросам:
1. Как в данном случае лучше сохранять информацию: JSON или в базу данных?
2. Нужно ли мне использовать Jetty?

Comment: Вы можете сохранять все в базу данных, а потом тянуть оттуда информацию. Используйте jpa + hibernate. Если вам нужно только заносить,читать,изменять данные, то этого достаточно. Если вы хотите сделать rest api , которое будет работать с базой, тогда нужно будет использовать jetty + сервлеты/jax-rs + jersey/ spring mvc ) .В этом случае rest api будет работать с жсоном/xml .

Comment: Я бы сделал в базу, ибо надежней и удобней.

Comment: поддерживаю решение с базой. старый-добрый ORM, если все это сделать правильно, используя hibernate+spring data, то можно практически забыть о бд и работать только с объектной моделью. очень просто и удобно

Comment: На предприятии стоит Microsoft SQL Server. Можно его использовать или лучше PostgreSQL, как во многих уроках по Hibernate пишут?

Comment: А какая, собственно, разница? Если вы все правильно делаете, то переход из одной SQL DB на другую SQL DB сводится к подмене JDBC-драйвера и диалекта. Задача досаточно тривиальная. Вы пишите простое приложение, создаете схему БД на вашем сервере. А потом через локальную сеть просто подключаетесь к этой базе данных. У меня , например, есть приложение, которое работает с Amazon RDS - облачный сервис для удаленных БД. Вот вам ссылка на репозиторий с дровами на Microsoft SQL https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc